# Bifurcation of Driven Chua's Circuit

Tags: ltspice

I am trying to create a bifurcation figure of the Chua circuit as shown in the figure. The 'x' in the figure is the voltage across the capacitor C and the F is the amplitude of the input signal. Here the input has been increased from 0 to 1. The other parameters are for Chua's diode. [image]

When I try the same circuit in Ltspice I am not getting a similar bifurcation figure. I get something like this.[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the link to the paper - [Link to the paper](https://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/pdf/10.1162/isal_a_039)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try this https://tinyurl.com/y4kg78cy

Comment: Can you provide a link to the paper? One that's not behind a pay-wall. There are details missing: how is the measuring done, what's `x` in the graph, the values, why did you set up your source as it is, etc.

Comment: I just added the link to the paper. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That bifurcation map can't be plotted in LTspice[*]. It involves running the simulation until the transients died out, then sampling the steady-state values at the end, which will form one slice on the Y-axis. Then a perturbance is introduced and the process is repeated for another slice.

To illustrate, consider the well-known logistic map, with the formula:

$$y_k=R\,y_{k-1}(1-y_{k-1})$$

For some given initial conditions, say \$R=2.7\$ and \$y_0=0.7\$, running the equation over some 30 steps results in this graph:

[image: 1]

The last value is considered to be in steady-state, so it's stored. Then the same process is repeated, until the result is the one in the [Wikipedia's logistic map's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map#Chaos_and_the_logistic_map).

If I read it correctly, the same process is done here. They start with a fixed value, to force the system to start in a known, stable region, forcing the other regions off, then they step the value (the first pulse), let the system stabilize, then measure, then the system is reset, then rinse and repeat. Note that they are not using the classic [Chua's circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chua%27s_circuit), but a modified one.

---

[*]Only one "slice" could be plotted in LTspice: a step source can be used as the input, and the simulation time adjusted to include only the last, steady-state part. Then use `.opt baudrate=<...>`. You'll be sorely disappointed, though. Best use Octave/Matlab/Scilab/whatever else for this task; SPICE is not the language for bifurcation maps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and the answer. It helped me a lot. Now I am using Matlab and as you have said, I run a code for input let's say square wave with 0.1 amplitude then I reset the circuit then again I run it for the 0.2 square waves, and so on but I am still getting similar results. I don't see any bifurcations. Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

Comment: @BirajShakya Are you after the same [reservoir computing (RC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_computing), using their methods? Is this only an intellctual curiosity, or so clearly defined goal?  If it's the latter, I'm afraid I can't help you, as I've never followed any RC-related paths. Or are you just looking to replicate the plot?

Comment: I am trying to replicate the plot and collect data for one of my projects. And I am using the same circuit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see *something similar to bifurcation diagram in the paper just for fun*, you can use an arbitrary behavioral voltage as below, though many details are not so definite at all as in the paper and it's not exactly bifurcation diagram.

[image: chua]